# Getting IP address of my computer

Tags: vb.net

How can I get the IP address of my computer (on which my application is running)
in vb.net

Thanks
Furqan

Comment: Some computers have multiple IP addresses. What should happen then?

Comment: does not matter ! I need any of them

Comment: What if one IP address is on an interface with internet access and another is on an interface with no internet access?

Comment: Actually I need to run a chat program over my local network (LAN), through my application.  For that I need IP address.  What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [`System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx), passing it the empty string. Note that it will give you an array of addresses, this is because a host can have multiple addresses, one for each interface. A common example would be the loopback address (127.0.0.1) and one or more public facing IP addresses (eg 10.10.1.1). If your machine has a specific host name you can use that instead of the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

See [System.Net.DNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx).

Something like this should work:

```
Dim ips As IPAddress() = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())

Dim index As Integer
For Each ip in ips
     Console.WriteLine(ip)
Next ip
```